# How to change a theme in Vue Native?

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

I use Vue Native and i'm trying to change theme. But StyleProvider is not taking the theme, and throwing warning "Failed prop type: Invalid prop style of type array supplied to StyleProvider, expected object." What i did wrong?

```
<template>
<nb-style-provider v-bind:style="getTheme(material)">
<nb-container>
<nb-text>Contact</nb-text>
</nb-container>
</nb-style-provider>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from "vue-native-core";
import {VueNativeBase} from "native-base";
import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
import material from './native-base-theme/variables/material';

Vue.use(VueNativeBase);
export default {
data: function() {
return {
getTheme: getTheme,
material: material,
};
},
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, You'll have to declare a separate react component to make use of native base theme and then import that component and reuse it in your vue component.